# Why is $T_n=Y_{n-1}+Y_n$ not a Markov chain?

Tags: markov-chains, martingales

Let $(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}$ be a sequence of iid random variables with an arbitrary distribution $q$ and existing expected value.

How can I prove that $T_n=Y_{n-1}+Y_n$ with $(T_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is not a Markov chain?

How can I prove if $T_n$ is a Martingale?

Comment: Suppose $Y_n$ are fair coin flips and $T_2 = 1$.  Then $P(T_3 = 0 \mid T_1 = 1, T_2 = 1) > 0$, but $P(T_3 = 0 \mid T_1 = 0, T_2 = 1) = 0$.

Comment: Not always true, take $(Y_n)$ as being $\equiv 0 $, then $T_n$ is a markov chain. Can you please be more precise?

Comment: @MarineGalantin: That's true.  OP, note that I only point out that $T_n$ is not *necessarily* a Markov chain, not that it cannot be.  Or was that directed to OP?  Or to both of us? :-)

Comment: That means $T_n$ can be a Markov chain? If this is so, then how can I prove it?

Comment: @BrianTung my comment wasn't directed to you, sorry for the misunderstanding :). Tino, it really depends on the case scenario you're dealing with. Your question as it is right now is neither true nor false.

Comment: $(T_n){n\in\mathbb{N}_0}$ is given and $(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}$ is an iid sequence with an arbitrary distribution $q$ and existing expected value. Do these information help to answer the question?

Comment: Can someone tell me, how to prove if $T_n$ is a Martingale?

Comment: Hi Tino, so if you want anyone to come back, little trick you should @ them. I missed your message :) and I wouldn't have if you had written @Marine... Back to the question, yes it helps, please update the above question and then @ me, saying it is done. However, If $Y_n$ is iid, what happens for $T_0$ ? What is $Y_{-1}$ ? Also, if the $Y_n$ are iid, i think it is a markov chain. I can also prove it is a martingale depending on the value of $Y_{-1}$ ... Update the question with the relevant information and I ll try my best to answer you!

Comment: @MarineGalantin Thank you for the trick :)  Unfortunately there is no information on $Y_{n-1}$. All the information I got, I have written in the comment (no. 6) above. Regarding Markov property: Can I prove that $T_n$ is not Markov with an example to show the opposite? Regarding Martingale property: Is is correct that $T_{n+1}=T_n+Y_{n+1}$? If the definition of martingale holds, then should it be $E[T_{n+1}|T_0,...,T_n]=T_n$ and $E[Y_{n+1}]=0$?

Comment: I don't need $Y_{n-1}$, I need $Y_{-1}$ otherwise your sequence of $T$ is ill-defined in $0$. Regarding your questions, yes, if you find an example where $T_n$ depends on the path, you found a counter example and thus it is not markov.

Comment: What for the martingale part, you just have to check the definition again.. meaning exactly what you wrote. What for the implications, I think the expectancy of $Y$ should be zero, but one should prove it. Either you prove it yourself, or if you modify the original question (there is an edit button), I d understand better your question and I ll answer it underneath :) In the actual state, your question at the top is not clear. Comments are not additional information about the question but a place for communication.

Comment: @MarineGalantin I have edit the original question, hope you'll understand the question better and answer it underneath :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still I maintain you haven't defined your sequence in $0$. What is $T_0$ ? So here, I assume $Y_n$ is define $\forall n \in \mathbb N_0$, and $T_n$ is $\forall n \in \mathbb N$.

**Markov**

$X_n$ is a Markov Chain 
$$\iff \mathbb E ( X_n | \mathcal F_{n-1} ) =  \mathbb E ( X_n | X_{n-1} ) $$

So, is $T_n$ a markov chain ? $T_n = Y_n + Y_{n-1} $

$$ \mathbb E ( T_n | \mathcal F_{n-1} ) = \mathbb E ( Y_n + Y_{n-1} | \mathcal F_{n-1} ) = \mathbb E ( Y_n ) + \mathbb E ( Y_{n-1} | Y_{n-1} )  
= \mathbb E ( T_n | Y_{n-1} ) $$
*About those equalities, depending on your level of proficiency with probability theory, you might need some details, let me know about that. All comes down to basic properties, like the one with independance between the condition and the random variable inside the conditional expectation.*

and $$ \mathbb E ( T_n | Y_{n-1} ) \neq   \mathbb E ( T_n | Y_{n-1} , Y_{n-2} ) = \mathbb E ( T_n | Y_{n-1} , Y_{n-2} ) = \mathbb E ( T_n | T_{n-1} ) $$

This is what's causing the problem according to me. You then have an example of a non markovian chain (first comment) given by Brian. However, you can easily modify your process to make it markovian with the proof I ve given you.

Also, check with the same steps what about the random walk $ T_n = T_{n-1} + Y_n $.

---

**Martingale**

$X_n$ is a Martingale
$$\iff \mathbb E ( X_n | \mathcal F_{n-1} ) =  X_{n-1} $$

Let's find a condition on the expectation of the $Y_n$.

$$ \mathbb E ( T_n | \mathcal F_{n-1} ) = \mathbb E ( Y_n + Y_{n-1} | \mathcal F_{n-1} ) = \mathbb E ( Y_n ) + \mathbb E ( Y_{n-1} | Y_{n-1} ) = \mathbb E ( Y_n ) + Y_{n-1} $$

can you conclude yourself ?

Comment: Do you mean $T_n$ is not a Martingale?

Comment: Yes, you can see it here, the result misses a random variable. Usually people look at random walk, not moving average processes. This is the reason why it doesn't work here. Also, simply checking the expectation is not enough, the definition is the one I wrote.